# sqlite How many characters of the _id TEXT column are considered unique?

Tags: android, sqlite

Sqlite on Android. 
How many characters of the _id TEXT column are considered unique?
All characters or first few

Comment: It's better to say - how many characters are used to determine the uniqueness of the string?  All characters or first few?

Answer (score 0):

if you use auto increment all are unique.

> Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated automatically when a new record is inserted into a table.
>
> Often this is the primary key field that we would like to be created automatically every time a new record is inserted.

Comment: I use the 36 character representation of the UUID, Do I exceed the length used by the engine? I observe ambiguous behavior under different versions Android API

Comment: I observe ambiguous behavior -  for example, the cursor.moveToFirst() causes an exception on API 19, but API 23 - not. The difference in the implementation of the API (I looked at the source code) is that the first one refers to the column _id

Comment: The question for me is removed - all 36 UUID symbols are used.

Comment: TEXT cannot be autoincrementing.

Answer (score 0):

Determining uniqueness is done with the normal comparison operations.

As mentioned in the [collating sequences documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation), all characters in a value are used for comparisons. (Unless you're explicitily using the RTRIM collation, but then you'd know about this.)